# Where CLR allocates local memory pool?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, clr

ECMA-335, I.12.3.2.4 states the following:

> Part of each method state is a local memory pool. Memory can be explicitly allocated from the local memory pool using the `localloc` instruction. All memory in the local memory pool is reclaimed on method exit, and that is the only way local memory pool memory is reclaimed (there is no instruction provided to free local memory that was allocated during this method invocation). The local memory pool is used to allocate objects whose type or size is not known at compile time and which the programmer does not wish to allocate in the managed heap. Because the local memory pool cannot be shrunk during the lifetime of the method, a language implementation cannot use the local memory pool for general-purpose memory allocation.

Where does CLR allocate this memory pool? Is it managed heap, thread stack, etc?

Comment: I can't say with any authority, but it sounds like stack allocation to me.  However, I suspect the standard doesn't explicitly require that in order to provide implementers greater flexibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is all intentionally vague because it is a strong implementation detail that the CLI spec doesn't want to nail down.  It peeks through the cracks in the MSDN article for [Opcodes.Localloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.localloc.aspx) though:

> StackOverflowException is thrown if there is insufficient memory to service the request.

There's only one way you ever get SOE: it requires allocating from the stack.

The C# language is less shy about where it gets allocated, it uses the *stackalloc* keyword.  A sample program:

```
class Program {
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args) {
        int* p = stackalloc int[42];
    }
}
```

Produces this IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s   42
  IL_0002:  conv.u
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0004:  mul.ovf.un
  IL_0005:  localloc                   // <=== Here
  IL_0007:  pop
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Which produces this machine code at runtime:

```
02E42620  push        ebp  
02E42621  mov         ebp,esp  
02E42623  sub         esp,8  
02E42626  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],esp  
02E42629  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],6A029823h  
02E42630  mov         eax,esp  
02E42632  test        dword ptr [esp],esp  
02E42635  sub         eax,0A8h                       // <=== Here
02E4263A  mov         esp,eax  
02E4263C  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],esp  
02E4263F  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-8],6A029823h  
02E42646  je          02E4264D  
02E42648  call        730CA5C0  
02E4264D  lea         esp,[ebp]  
02E42650  pop         ebp  
02E42651  ret
```

The `sub eax,0A8h` instruction subtracts 0xa8 = 168 = 42x4 bytes from the ESP register (the stack pointer), the `mov esp,eax` instruction adjusts the stack pointer.  So yes, this definitely comes from the stack.